# Unable to display NSString in Xcode 9.2 debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode has suddenly stopped being able to display NSString's to me - instead it will only show the addresses, even if I do `po myString`.

The program executes perfectly. If I use `NSLog` to send the string to the console then that works.

It's making debugging very hard - has anyone got a solution to this?

`(lldb) p settingsPath
(NSString *) $1 = 0x00007ffeefbf9820
(lldb) po settingsPath
0x00007ffeefbf9820`